# List<> melhor prática, iniciar com capacidade fixa ou iniciar sem limite?

Tags: c#, desempenho

Tenho um cenário onde irei receber uma lista, ou um array, ou qualquer outro tipo de dado do banco de dados onde consigo saber o tamanho da minha lista antes de criá-la, qual a vantagem entre a **newList** e a **newList2** no meu código abaixo ? Existe algum benefício de performance nesse caso?
Os tipos (`int` e `object`) são apenas para ilustrar o exemplo.

```
public Task TestMethod(List<int> amounts)
{
    List<object> newList = new List<object>(amounts.Count);
    List<object> newList2 = new List<object>();
}
```

Comment: Se a performance for uma preocupação então crie a List indicando a sua capacidade.

Comment: A diferença é significativa? Essa é a minha dúvida, se compensa mesmo.

Comment: Se conhece a capacidade porque não usá-la? Não terá mais trabalho se o fizer, então compensa, seja a diferença significativa ou não.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Fiz um teste com ambos os casos e a performance foi irrelevante, com valores pequenos, mas a locação de memória é algo que deve ser levado em consideração.

Quando você criar a lista com *capacity* 0 (zero), o .NET irá aumentar e alocar espaço dinamicamente conforme novos itens forem sendo adicionados à lista, sempre dobrando a capacidade anterior, ou seja, na potência de 2. Em termos práticos, se sua lista tem 2 elementos e sua capacidade é de 2, ao adicionar mais um elemento ele dobra a capacidade, alocando espaço para 4 elementos. Até ai tudo bem, mas como é exponencial, quando você tiver 64 elementos e adicionar mais um, será alocado uma capacidade para 128, e assim por diante. Se você tiver 8192 elementos e adicionar outro, a capacidade vai para 16384 e assim por diante.

Com isso podemos concluir que, do ponto de vista de espaço e alocação de memória, é mais vantajoso definir a capacidade da lista se soubermos o tamanho e esse for grande. Quanto é grande? Teria que analisar o tipo de objeto que vai na lista para calcular a memória alocada, mas algo com mais de 1000 itens já seria interessante definir a capacidade.

Aqui um código que demostra isso:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<int> lista = new System.Collections.Generic.List<int>();
Random rand = new Random();
int i =0;
while (i < 1000)
{
    lista.Add(rand.Next(0, 20000));
    i++;
    Console.Write("\nTamanho: " + lista.Count.ToString());
    Console.Write("  Capidade: " + lista.Capacity.ToString());
}
```

Pode ser executado aqui: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5Kw99i

Exemplo da saída:

> Tamanho: 31  Capidade: 32
>   Tamanho: 32  Capidade: 32
>   Tamanho: 33  Capidade: 64
>   Tamanho: 34  Capidade: 64

Note que a capacidade dobra, e logo o espaço alocado em memória também.

**EDIT**: executei o mesmo código no dotnetfiddle com 50.000, 500.000 e 1.000.000 de itens, sem inicializar a capacidade e inicializando. Abaixo os resultados demostrando a diferença no consumo de memória. Mais uma vez, a performance do ponto de vista de tempo/cpu foi irrelevante:

```
+-----------+------------------+------------------+
| Itens     | Sem inicializar  | Inicializando    |
+-----------+------------------+------------------+
| 50.000    | Memory: 512.23kb | Memory: 195.34kb |
+-----------+------------------+------------------+
| 500.000   | Memory: 4.01Mb   | Memory: 1.91Mb   |
+-----------+------------------+------------------+
| 1.000.000 | Memory: 8.01Mb   | Memory: 3.81Mb   |
+-----------+------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Ricardo, exemplo perfeito,  era realmente onde queria chegar, a aplicação em que trabalho qualquer mínimo detalhe de performance é muito importante. Usamos benchmark pra tudo e me deparei com uma mudança onde tinham alterado usando o limite.

Answer (score 6):

A vantagem de usar a lista com uma capacidade definida é que não haverá realocação futura dos itens da lista. Quando você usa uma lista sem definir o tamanho, ela [começa com a capacidade zero e vai crescendo a medida que você precisa](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y52x03h2(v=vs.110).ASPX). A capacidade sempre vai ser maior ou igual o número de elementos da lista.

Resumindo, você ganha em performance usando uma lista com capacidade definida porque internamente o C# não vai precisar realocar os elementos existentes para adicionar um novo.

Answer (score 1):

Se nada for especificado ela começa com capacidade 0 e pula para 4 se adicionar uma item. Depois vai dobrando de capacidade sempre que que ocupar todos os espaços livres. Pelo menos é a implementação atual, nada garante que isto sempre será assim.

Se você já sabe quantos elementos a lista terá, ou pelo menos algo aproximado, haverá ganho em definir a capacidade inicial para evitar realocação de memória. Se você tem a informação existe zero vantagem em não colocar a capacidade inicial, mesmo que o ganho não seja tão grande, e ele não é tão pequeno assim. Sem indicar a capacidade fica uns 40-50% mais lento, isto em um sistema operacional que faz otimizações em realocações, se não tiver isto, pode virar uma tragédia.

Além de ter que realocar memória toda vez que aumenta o tamanho coloca pressão no *garbage collector*, o que o acionará mais vezes e com pausas maiores. Em geral os testes que as pessoas fazem ignoram isto. Devemos sempre evitar alocação, mesmo pequenas. E muitas alocação não são facilmente visíveis, o que é o caso de uma lista em crescimento.

É preferível alocar mais elementos do que vai usar do que ficar fazer realocação de memória. Claro que sempre tem um ponto que pode não compensar.